# Build loadable Kernel Module while building Android custom ROM

Tags: android, linux-kernel, makefile

1. built Goldfish kernel successfully.
2. built Android custom ROM with pre-built Goldfish kernel successfully.
3. Added module source code (Hello-Proc for example) and Makefile to one folder in the custom ROM. I could **manually** build *Hello-Proc.ko* successfully by issuing "make" in the folder.

Which makefile and how need I change to trigger building this module when I build the ROM so that *Hello-Proc.ko* will be built **automatically**?

Note: Goldfish kernel code is not in the Android custom ROM, and Android custom ROM will not build Goldfish kernel neither. The file tree looks like this.

```
├── android_AOSP
│   ├── device
│       ├── vendor_A 
│           ├── product_A
│           │   ├── AndroidBoard.mk
│           │   ├── AndroidProducts.mk
│           │   ├── BoardConfig.mk
│           │   ├── device.mk
│           │   ├── product_a.mk
│           │   ├── system.prop
│           │   └── vendorsetup.sh
│           ├── modules
│               ├── Android.mk
│               ├── hello_proc
│                  ├── Android.mk
│                  ├── hello_proc.c
│                  ├── Kbuild
│                  ├── Makefile
├── goldfish
```

Answer (score 0):

.ko is the kernel module. It must be built and loaded in the Linux kernel (Goldfish in your case). You have put it in AOSP which is not correct. AOSP defines the user space and above of Android stack .

Comment: In fact, the build is for Android Emulator currently. I intent not to build Goldfish with ROM build. Because module build needs a kernel file tree, I added the goldfish there. Do you imply I have to move goldfish under AOSP to achieve my goal?

Comment: Can you explain briefly what functionality you are trying to achieve, maybe then I can suggest where to put the module.

Comment: Checkout this video to better understand the kernel and AOSP - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLUXPxxJc5c

Comment: Ramesh, I want Hello-Proc.ko to be built automatically while I build Android ROM. Now I have to build the module manually before I start Android ROM build.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the AOSP build recipe does not including building the kernel. It has to be built separately using the provided tool chain. Checkout this guide if you have not (http://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html).

To build a loadable kernel module, add your code to the kernel source (find the repo in the link above).

Comment: that link only has nexus kernels

Answer (score 0):

**compile the kernel with Clang (inline with a custom ROM)**
1.Add the Clang commits to your kernel source
2.Make sure your ROM has [this commit](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_vendor_lineage/commit/da32895b61ef2b3e8899f011110f8eab11da5470)
3.Add the following to your BoardConfig.mk file in your device tree: TARGET_KERNEL_CLANG_COMPILE := true

To test and verify everything is working:

1.Build a kernel image: m kernel or m bootimage
2.Open the out/target/product/*/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/include/generated/compile.h file and look at the LINUX_COMPILER option.